# How to iterate a sync iterator and an async generator with the same for statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I had this simple sync code:

```
if item:
    items = [item]
else:
    items = get_items()
for i in items:
    # do something
```

Now `get_items` is an async generator. `for i in items` won't work with an async generator, and `async for i in items` won't iterate over my `[item]` list.

Is there a way of iterating over a variable that could be a normal iterator or an async generator?

If not, can I create a one-liner ad-hoc async generator that simply yields this one `item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of iterating over a variable that could be a normal iterator or an async generator?

Not without an adapter, which you must provide yourself. For example:

```
async def as_aiter(it):
    for val in it:
        yield val
```

With that helper in place, the following will work:

```
if item:
    items = as_aiter([item])
else:
    items = get_items()
async for i in items:
    # do something
```

> If not, can I create a one-liner ad-hoc async generator that simply yields this one `item`?

While [PEP 530](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/) does define async generator expressions, they are not useful here because they require an async iterator to iterate over, and that's what we're trying to create.

Although technically not a one-liner, a simple and short option is to create a generator and immediately instantiate it:

```
if item:
    async def gen_item(): yield item
    items = gen_item()
else:
    items = get_items()
```

It's easy to generalize it into a helper such as:

```
async def aiter_once(val):
    yield val
```

and write `items = aiter_once(item)`, but that again requires the `aiter_once` helper to be defined somewhere in the code.

The [`aiostream`](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream) package is worth mentioning for its nice collection of stream operators, including [`aiostream.stream.just`](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators.html#aiostream.stream.just), which creates an async stream that produces a single value. However, it requires a `with` statement around the `for` loop, which makes it unergonomic for your use case.